# WCF operationContext returns gateway instead of client ip address

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf, ip-address

im kinda new to developing WCF services. I'm using this code to get the client ip address,

```
private String getRemoteIP()
{
    OperationContext context = OperationContext.Current;
    MessageProperties prop = context.IncomingMessageProperties;
    RemoteEndpointMessageProperty endpoint = prop[RemoteEndpointMessageProperty.Name] as RemoteEndpointMessageProperty;
    return endpoint.Address;
}
```

in my localhost it works fine, but when i install my service in a server for testing, what I get in return is the client's gateway, any insight on the reason why that could be ???

Comment: From the point of view of a server. a client sitting behind a NAT gateway the gateway IS their IP address, that's how NAT works.

Answer (score 1):

try this one instead:
First of all enable AspNetCompatibility mode, as follows:

```
<system.serviceModel>
        <!-- this enables WCF services to access ASP.Net http context -->
        <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true"/>
</system.serviceModel>
```

And then you can get the IP address by:

```
HttpContext.Current.Request.UserHostAddress
```